# Getting users with a specific meta data and then querying their posts?

Tags: php, user-meta

Basically what I want to do is first get users with a specific meta_key and meta_value.

And then query their posts.

Right now I'm using this:

```
        <?php 

$user_ids = get_users([
    'meta_key' => 'userfunds',
    'meta_value' => '10', 
    'fields' => 'ID',
]);

$posts = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author__in' => $user_ids,
    'orderby'               => 'rand'
]);



if( $posts ): ?>
    
        
        
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        
setup_postdata( $post )
        
?>

<?php the_title(); ?>


<?php endforeach; ?>
    
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But `get_users` part doesn't do anything.

I mean, I could enter any non existing `meta_key` or `meta_value` and it is still displaying all user posts.

So I guess I have made a mistake somewhere in the code.

Basically it ignores the $user_ids variable.

The `WP_Query` does it's job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have ID in the args?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that here: `$posts = new WP_Query`, the `$posts` is not an array of posts and instead, it's an object. So instead of doing the `foreach` and `setup_postdata()`, you should just use the `while ( $posts->have_posts() ) ...` method to display the loop. But then I guessed you originally used `$posts = get_posts()` there?

> I mean, I could enter any non existing `meta_key` or `meta_value` and it is still displaying all user posts.

> So I guess I have made a mistake somewhere in the code.

No, you did not, and the problem is neither with `get_users()`.

It's just that when you use a non-existent meta key/value, then that means `get_users()` will return an empty array which is then passed to `WP_Query` via the `author__in` argument, and when it is an empty array, then `WP_Query` will not limit the query to certain post authors only, so `'author__in' => array()` is actually the same as *not* setting that argument and thus, what you get when it's not set would be the same as what you'd get when it's set to an empty array.

Therefore, what you would want to do is, run the `new WP_Query` only if the `$user_ids` is not empty, like so:

```php
if ( ! empty( $user_ids ) ) {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'author__in' => $user_ids,
        // ... your other args.
    ]);

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sally! Yeah I read later on that it's an object. I used your code and it worked great. Thanks for your help!